# Script Linux - Procurar, Copiar, Colar e Alterar valos de arquivos te texto

Tags: python, linux, bash, script, perl

Eu Tenho esses 3 arquivos: 
**`Access.txt`**: Arquivo de texto grande, com registros por linha e colunas separadas por " **`;`** ".
**`NewAcess.txt`**: Lista de novos acessos para adicionar. 
**`NewUsers.txt`**: Lista de novos usuários para adicionar.

Exemplo de Arquivos:

**`Access.txt`**:

> (rec;john;arquivo.txt;teste.arquivo.050)
>   (rec;mike;arquivo.txt;teste.arquivo.010)
>   (snd;mary;testaaa.txt;sendt.asdttvo.100)
>   (rec;john;notepad.txt;novo.testetto.002)

**`NewAccess.txt`**:

> (teste.arquivo.010)
>   (sendt.asdttvo.100)

**`NewUsers.txt`**:

> (suzy;john)

Preciso de ajuda para criar um script que faça as seguintes ações:

1. Criar um *backup* do arquivo **`Access.txt`**.
2. Procurar no arquivo **`Access.txt`** cada um dos valores do arquivo **`NewAccess.txt`** (ex: test.arquivo.010) e copiar a linha referente à primeira correspondência de cada critério (do arquivo **`NewAccess.txt`**) para um nova linha e substituir na nova linha o campo do nome do usuário por cada um dos nomes em **`NewUsers.txt`**.

Resultado Final Pretendido:

**`Access.txt`**:

> (rec;john;arquivo.txt;teste.arquivo.050)
>   (rec;mike;arquivo.txt;teste.arquivo.010)
>   (snd;mary;testaaa.txt;sendt.asdttvo.100)
>   (rec;john;notepad.txt;novo.testetto.002)
>   (rec;suzy;arquivo.txt;teste.arquivo.010)
>   (snd;suzy;testaaa.txt;sendt.asdttvo.100)
>   (rec;john;arquivo.txt;teste.arquivo.010)
>   (snd;john;testaaa.txt;sendt.asdttvo.100)

Estou pensando em separar nos seguintes passos:
Procurar as linhas correspondentes e copiá-las para outro arquivo **`Access_temp.txt`**.
Mudar a segunda coluna (a partir do 5º `char`) do novo arquivo **`Access_temp.txt`** com o nome dos novos usuários.
Colar o conteúdo do arquivo **`Access_temp.txt`** (usuário substituído) para o arquivo **`Access.txt`**.

Comecei tentando com o seguinte comando:

```
grep -Fwf NewAccess.txt Access.txt > Access_temp.txt
```

Mas eu preciso que o *grep* me traga apenas o primeiro resultado de cada critério do arquivo **`NewAcess.txt`**, mas não sei como fazer isso.

Preciso muito de ajuda para montar esse *script*, não conheço *scripts* em Linux.

Muito Obrigado!

Comment: É `python` ou é `perl`?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento: Acho que tanto faz. Fiquei com a impressão de que qualquer coisa que rode fácil no Linux serve.

Comment: @hugomg realmente em linux temos muitas facilidades (apesar de haver o mito de que é o contrário), mas em questão de formular a pergunta me soa sem foco

Comment: Pode ser em qualquer linguagem. Não conheço bem nenhuma delas. Estou começando em Linux agora. Acho que pode ser em Bash (Shell) mesmo, Python ou Perl, a quer for melhor para este caso. Obrigado!!

Comment: Acho pena a suspensão desta pergunta.